# Cocartesian edge gives contractible choice of filling in commutative diagram

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

This appears on p. 192 of Land's *Introduction to Infinity-Categories* which is the first page of his section on Straightening-Unstraightening.

Let $p:\mathscr{E} \to \mathscr{C}$ be a cocartesian fibration between $\infty$-categories. For a map $f:x \to y$ in $\mathscr{C}$, two lifts $z,z' \in \mathscr{E}$ of $x$ and a map $\alpha :z \to z'$ in $\mathscr{E}$ there are $p$-cocartesian lifts $z \to f_!(z)$ and $z' \to f_!(z')$ of $f$ using that $p$ is a cocartesian fibration. Since $z\to f_!(z)$ is $p$-cocartesian we can fill in the bottom arrow (I don't know how to draw dashed arrows on MSE) to obtain a commutative diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
 z @>>> z'\\
    @V V V @VV V\\
    f_!(z) @>>{\exists}> f_!(z')
\end{CD}
**Question.** Land then says that there is only a contractible choice of arrows $f_!(z) \to f_!(z')$ making this diagram commutative because $z\to f_!(z)$ is $p$-cocartesian. Why?

I probably missed some result about $p$-cocartesian edges (and/or lack understanding in some result) and would appreciate some clearing up about this.

Comment: Do you understand the analogous uniqueness result for Grothendieck opfibrations, in ordinary category theory?

Comment: @ZhenLin No, I have basically no knowledge of the Grothendieck construction (I should read up on it...). Are you saying that the argument is analogous?

Comment: I would not say the argument is analogous. I would say the concept is the same. (In fact, a functor of ordinary categories, considered as a morphism of simplicial sets by the nerve construction, is a cocartesian fibration if and only if the functor is a Grothendieck opfibration.) I definitely recommend you try to understand the ordinary category theory concept before trying to make sense of the quasicategory version.

Comment: Morally, this is true by definition. Perhaps not helpful, of course :) It might help if you explain what exactly *you* think a $p$-cocartesian edge is.

Comment: @KevinArlin Land defined it as an edge such that every left horn $\Lambda^n_0$ (for $n \geq 2$) starting from that edge admits a lift to the entire simplex $\Delta^n$ wrt $p$.

Comment: @QiZhu Right, so you want to show that the space of $\Delta^2$s restricting to a given $\Lambda^2_0$ is contractible. You can write down a $\Lambda^3_0$ giving two points in this space, fill to get connectedness, and so on for all homotopy groups.

Comment: @KevinArlin Ah I see, that's nice, thank you! I think I'm satisfied with it for now and will try to make every detail precise when I have time for that.